# How to append JS files in NUXT before </body> ends

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Im trying to append javascript files in NUXT.
but when i use nuxt.config to append javascript it works but not as I want.

```
 head: {
    title: 'mynuxt',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Nuxt.js project' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/css/bootstrap.min.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/css/mdb.min.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/css/style.min.css' },
    ],
    script: [
          { src: '/js/bootstrap.min.js' },
          { src: '/js/popper.min.js' },
          { src: '/js/mdb.min.js' }
    ],
  },
```

when i inspect element it inserted but in head.
[image]

Ive search already in google but did not found any solution yet. thanks in advance

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have two options:

**Option 1** - With guide Nuxt.js is recommended add `.js` in folder `plugin`

https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins

Example:

Add new file in `plugins/example.js`

Then, add the file inside the plugins key of `nuxt.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ['~/plugins/example']
}
```

**Option 2** - Use in **metadata** with `body: true`

```
<script>
export default {
  head: {
    script: [
      { src: '/head.js' },
      // Supported since Nuxt 1.0
      { src: '/body.js', body: true },
      { src: '/defer.js', defer: '' }
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

More info: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2000#issuecomment-341380762

Comment: should i reside my js files from plugins not on static sir?

Comment: @WinstonFale I do not know what your goal is, why do you want to put out the Vue or in the plugin?? in the plugin any `.js` works, static too.

Comment: i have static js for a theme. i already import css. using head > link from nuxt.config. but it has also custom javascripts which is required to be put before closing of </body>. it is not working when i put in header because it will find element that is not existing yet.

Comment: @WinstonFale Try `{ src: '/example.js', body: true },` with `body:true`

Comment: thanks you so much adriano
meta data {body:true}
works for me

Comment: how can add js files from node_module this way?

Answer (score 3):

For Nuxt-3.0.0 (final) you can control the insertion behavior of several tags directly inside a component using e.g.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
  useHead({
   script: [
     {
       type: 'text/javascript',
       innerHTML: 'Code goes here...',
       tagPosition: 'bodyClose | bodyOpen | head',
     }
   ]
  });
</script>
```

The script will be put

- `bodyClose` -> ending of body
- `bodyOpen` -> start of body
- `head` -> head (default)

Or you can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75006796/19901666) where it is explained how to put a script tag inside a component's template section.

Answer (score 2):

in nuxt3 just add `body:true`

example:

```
app: {
    head: {
      title: 'title',
      charset: 'utf-8',
      meta: [
        { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' }
      ],
      link: [
        { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/layout/css/bootstrap.css' },
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/layout/vendors/chartjs/Chart.min.css' },
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/layout/vendors/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.css' },
        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/layout/css/app.css' }
      ],
      noscript: [
        { children: 'Javascript is required' }
      ],
      script: [
        { src: '/layout/vendors/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js', body: true },
        { src: '/layout/js/app.js', body: true },
        { src: '/layout/vendors/chartjs/Chart.min.js', body: true },
        { src: '/layout/vendors/apexcharts/apexcharts.min.js', body: true },
        { src: '/layout/js/pages/dashboard.js', body: true },
        { src: '/layout/js/main.js', body: true }
      ]
    }
  },
```