# Nuxt - add script to head and body

Tags: nuxt.js

I am trying to use this script in my Nuxt app, but can't figure out how. In a basic HTML file, it works fine. This is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>outdooractive platform - API Template</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    
    <!-- load Outdooractive Javascript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" 
            src="//www.outdooractive.com/alpportal/oa_head.js?proj=api-dev-oa&amp;key=yourtest-outdoora-ctiveapi&amp;lang=en"></script>


  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- container used by FlexView API -->
    <div class="oax-top-cont"></div>


    <!-- and some lines of javascript inside a script tag -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var conf = {
          frontendtype:   "tour",          // choose content type
          zoom:           11,              // set initial zoom level
          center:       [ 10.292, 47.546 ] // set initial map center
      };
      
      var fvp = oa.api.flexviewpage( conf );

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried this approach, but it returns with an error that `api doesn't exist`

```js
data() {
    return {
      conf: {
        frontendtype: 'tour',
        zoom: 11,
        center: [10.292, 47.546]
      }
    }
  },
  head() {
    return {
      script: [
        {
          src: '//www.outdooractive.com/alpportal/oa_head.js?proj=api-dev-oa&amp;key=yourtest-outdoora-ctiveapi&amp;lang=en'
        },
        {
          body: true,
          fvp: this.oa.api.flexviewpage(this.conf) // attempt one
          fvp: () => {this.oa.api.flexviewpage(this.conf)} // attempt two
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I am still fairly new so would really appreciate some help, and perhaps a description of why the `var fvp` is recognized in a plain HTML file, but not with Nuxt.

Thank you

Comment: does the `conf`/`fvp` same  no matter what url/page is? Or different pages have different `conf`/`fvp`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simplest way for Nuxt 2:

[custom your `index.html`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/concepts/views/#document-apphtml)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head {{ HEAD_ATTRS }}>
    {{ HEAD }}
    <!-- load Outdooractive Javascript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.outdooractive.com/alpportal/oa_head.js?proj=api-dev-oa&amp;key=yourtest-outdoora-ctiveapi&amp;lang=en"></script>

  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    {{ APP }}

    <!-- container used by FlexView API -->
    <div class="oax-top-cont"></div>


    <!-- and some lines of javascript inside a script tag -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var conf = {
          frontendtype:   "tour",          // choose content type
          zoom:           11,              // set initial zoom level
          center:       [ 10.292, 47.546 ] // set initial map center
      };
      
      var fvp = oa.api.flexviewpage( conf );

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

if the `conf` value is dynamic, you can add it in your `head()`

```js
data() {
  return {
    conf: {
      frontendtype: 'tour',
      zoom: 11,
      center: [10.292, 47.546]
    }
  }
},
head(){
  return {
    script: [
      {
        src: '//www.outdooractive.com/alpportal/oa_head.js?proj=api-dev-oa&amp;key=yourtest-outdoora-ctiveapi&amp;lang=en'
      },
      {
        type:'text/javascript',
        innerHTML: JSON.stringify(this.conf)
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> Please note that the `Script` component has been deprecated as of Nuxt 3.0.0-rc.14 and the suggested method is now `useHead`
> https://github.com/nuxt/framework/releases/tag/v3.0.0-rc.14

In Nuxt 3 you simply use the `Script` component, eg:

```
<Script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXXX-X"></Script>
```

or

```
<Script>
   // some JS code
</Script>
```

Note that most things that typically go in the head portion of the document now have components. There is also the `useHead` composable. See https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-head

Comment: The link is broken, can you update it?
https://nuxt.com/docs/examples/composables/use-head#usehead
This is an example

Comment: Updated useHead link

Answer (score 2):

For Nuxt3 the solution given above didn't lead to success for component related insertions in template section but only for head insertions. Instead this worked pretty nicely for components:

```js
// ScriptTag.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
  defineProps({
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'text/javascript',
      required: false,
    },
    async: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined,
      required: false,
    },
    defer: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined,
      required: false,
    },
  });
</script>

<template>
  <Component 
    :is="'script'" 
    :type="type" 
    :async="async ? async : undefined"
    :defer="defer ? defer : undefined"
  >
    <slot />
  </Component>
</template>
```

Usage
(it might be necessary to wrap *ScriptTag* in *ClientOnly*):

```js
<template>
  <ScriptTag async="true">
    // Code here
  </ScriptTag>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another choose is

Load ~/static folder script in nuxt.config.js,

```js
      head: {
        ...
        script: [
          { src: '/js/script_name.js' } // load script in your static folder
        ]
      }
```

and put youar sciprt into ~/js/script_name.js

Answer (score -1):

This is [the best answer I've found on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64233657/include-a-custom-script-in-the-head-tag-in-nuxt). Like larrykkk says above, you can put scripts in the *static* dir and load them from there.