# LaTeX rendering with MathJax

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I tried to use the library [mathjax](https://github.com/justforuse/vue-mathjax-next), but it didn't work in Nuxt 3

```
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea v-model="formula"/>
    <vue-mathjax :formula="formula"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const formula = ref('$$x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}.$$');

</script>
```

`/plugins`

```
import VueMathjax from 'vue-mathjax-next';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(({ vueApp }) => {
    vueApp.use(VueMathjax)
})
```

```
- Client vnode: span 
- Server rendered DOM: <!---->  
  at <VueMathjax formula="$$x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}.$$" > 
  at <Test onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <RouteProvider key="/test" vnode= {__v_isVNode: true, __v_skip: true, type: {…}, props: {…}, key: null, …} route= {fullPath: '/test', hash: '', query: {…}, name: 'test', path: '/test', …}  ... > 
  at <BaseTransition onAfterLeave= [ƒ] mode="out-in" appear=false  ... > 
  at <Transition onAfterLeave= [ƒ] name="page" mode="out-in" > 
  at <RouterView name=undefined route=undefined > 
  at <NuxtPage> 
  at <Default ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <LayoutLoader key="default" layoutProps= {ref: RefImpl} name="default" > 
  at <NuxtLayoutProvider layoutProps= {ref: RefImpl} key="default" name="default"  ... > 
  at <NuxtLayout> 
  at <App key=3 > 
  at <NuxtRoot>
```

I tried to use the library [vue-mathjax-next](https://github.com/justforuse/vue-mathjax-next), but it didn't work in Nuxt 3
The goal is to be able to render such text using Latex.

````
Cross out the common factor: $\dfrac{7}{10}$
Multiply a number to both the numerator and the denominator: $\dfrac{7}{10} \times \dfrac{10}{10}$
Write as a single fraction: $\dfrac{7 \times 10}{10 \times 10}$
Calculate the product or quotient: $\dfrac{70}{100}$
Rewrite a fraction with denominator equals 100 to a percentage: $70\%$```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment in the [related repo for the Vue2] version, it looks like you need to include the MathJax script, as the component doesn't load it itself.

In Nuxt 3, you can place a script in your component using the `<Script>` tag instead of `<script>`. [[ref]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70284856/nuxt-add-script-to-head-and-body)

> Please note that the Script component has been deprecated as of Nuxt 3.0.0-rc.14 and the suggested method is now useHead
>
> https://github.com/nuxt/framework/releases/tag/v3.0.0-rc.14

Updating your vue file to this should do the trick:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea v-model="formula"/>
    <vue-mathjax :formula="formula"/>
  </div>
  <Script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML"></Script>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const formula = ref('$$x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}.$$');
</script>
```

Comment: When I navigate to another page and then return back, the library stops working. Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to sit down and look at this further, but I would imagine the MathJax library doesn't have any listeners for Vue router changes. You'll likely need to look into MathJax further to determine if there's a way to indicate that the library should re-crawl the page and render formulas.

Comment: Yes, this can be done by calling MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub]);.